# Facebook like button should display like_count and not total_count

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

The like count displayed next to the facebook like button represents the totat_count which is the sum of share_count and like_count. Is it possible to display only the like_count instead of total_count?

Answer (score 1):

No, It's not possible to show just the like_count on facebook like button.

But it's possible to fetch like_count using their API, Here's the FQL link which outputs

> share_count, like_count, comment_count and total_count

Link:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27facebook.com%27
```